# Why the assigning method to generic Func<> is not possible

Tags: c#

I'm trying to understand why I can't return a method from object as a generic `Func<>` from a function, but on the other hand, I can pass the same method as a generic `Func<>` via parameters.

Please analyze the following example:

```
public class SomeDto1
{
}

public class SomeDto2
{
}

public class Foo1
{
  public static SomeDto1 Retrieve(int number)
  {
    // do sth with number
    return new SomeDto1();
  }
}

public class Foo2
{
  public static SomeDto2 Get(int number)
  {
    // do sth with number
    return new SomeDto2();
  }
}

public class DoSthWithMethods
{
  private void DoSth<T>(Func<int, T> method)
  {
    var dto = method(16);
    // do sth with dto
  }

  public IEnumerable<Func<int, T>> DoSth2<T>()
  {
    // this is not legal
    yield return Foo1.Retrieve;
    yield return Foo2.Get;
  }

  public void DoSth3()
  {
    // this is legal
    DoSth(Foo1.Retrieve);
    DoSth(Foo2.Get);
  }
}
```

Method `DoSth3` can correctly pass `Foo1.Retrieve` and `Foo2.Get` to `DoSth`, but I can't write code like in method `DoSth2`, because it wouldn't compile.

I want to understand why `DoSth2` is incorrect and how possibly I can correct it to be able to return the collection of methods via generic `Func<>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the compiler error:

> error CS0407: 'SomeDto1 Foo1.Retrieve(int)' has the wrong return type

The compiler knows that `Foo1.Retrieve` returns a `SomeDto1`. However, the method `DoSth2` is supposed to return a `Func<int, T>` *for any `T`*. You could call `DoSth<string>()`, and it's supposed to return a collection of `Func<int, string>`s. However, `SomeDto` is obviously not a `string`, so this is obviously not possible.

Answer (score 3):

By calling this:

```
DoSth(Foo1.Retrieve);
```

You are declaring `T` as `SomeDto1` by calling the method, and the compiler lets you ommit the declaration of `T`, so its equal to calling it like this:

```
DoSth<SomeDto1>(Foo1.Retrieve);
```

But when you do this:

```
public IEnumerable<Func<int, T>> DoSth2<T>()
{
  // this is not legal
  yield return Foo1.Retrieve;
  yield return Foo2.Get;
}
```

What is `T` in this case?

Who would prevent just calling the method like this `DoSth2<string>()`?

And this is the reason you are getting the mentioned error, because Foo1.Retrieve just simply isn't `Func<int, T>` as `T` could be of any type.

Comment: It's `DoSth<SomeDto1>(Foo1.Retrieve);` not `DoSth<int>(Foo1.Retrieve);`

Comment: @juharr - thx, fixed it always forget what the order of `Func<T1, T2>` is. Can't seem to memorize that the return value is the last `Tx`, stupid brain of mine.

Answer (score 2):

It is wrong because you are trying to return `Func<int, SomeDto1>` and `Func<int, SomeDto2>` as `Func<int, T>` and both dto's are not guaranteed to be `T`. For example what should happen if somebody calls your `DoSth2` like this: `DoSthWithMethods.DoSth2<string>()`?

As for why `DoSthWithMethods.DoSth` works you have situation turned around, when you call `DoSth(Foo1.Retrieve)` compiler determines that `Foo1.Retrieve` is `Func<int, SomeDto1>` so it can resolve generic parameter and you actually have `DoSthWithMethods.DoSth<SomeDto1>()`.